# How to track site search without query parameters in the URL?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, search, google-tag-manager, site-search

I want to be able to track the site searches, but the site search on my site is not a dynamic search. Users can’t just type and enter the search button. They have to click on a pre-set result that Elasticsearch shows to them. There are no query parameters or anything related to search in the URL that the user lands.

In these circumstances, is there still a way to track the site search in Analytics? Here’s my website if you need to check:  [www.etstur.com](http://www.etstur.com)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your site isn't in English, so it is a bit hard for me, but are you talking about the hotel search on your front page?     If so, it is having problems.   The date fields don't work.  I click on them and nothing happens.   When I click ARA I get taken to a "429 Too Many Requests nginx/1.17.6" error

Comment: Hi Stephen. Yes, I'm talking about the hotel search widget. 429 error should only happen if the client makes too many requests consecutively. Maybe it was a temporary error. could you try again, please? You don't have to select a date to make a search. Please try this: 1) Type "Antalya" to the search box. 2) Click to the first result 3) Click "Ara". Here's the screenshot step by step https://i.imgur.com/iOLkdZ8.png

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I understand the requests issue as it is likely using a limited free API, but the date fields worked for me...and I did get a search result

Comment: Would you like to track their initial query that results in the suggestion of Elasticsearch? Or do you want to track what was eventually chosen from the list populated by elastic search?